# When should comments be flagged as "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged two comments in [IE ignores my js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343179/ie-ignores-my-js)

> If IE ignores your JS, let your JS ignore IE as well!

and

> If you're sure that your javascript setting in IE was on but your script doesn't run,, just uninstall your IE, and try running with other cool browser like chrome and mozilla. It's easy.. hha

Both flags were declined. So, when is "not constructive" an appropriate flag? It seems I have a different definition for that.

Comment: Had a situation like this (in fact the comment was even mildly offensive). I checked my declined flag months later, only to find someone actually deleted the comment (as it should have been in the first place).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened there. The first comment almost seems like "stop supporting IE" only worse, so it's borderline at best. The second comment is clearly just someone being silly.  I deleted both of them. I think you're using the "not constructive" comment flag appropriately.

Answer (score 9):

I feel that your flags were justified, and flagged the very same comment (I noticed the second one was deleted).

**Not Constructive** should be flagged to any comment which has 0 value for the discussion. The comments are meant to be used as aids, to deliver secondary info, or request some. Jokes are nice and all, but if someone flagged it, it means that someone thought it was useless/not funny/not supposed to be there. That's where the line is drawn.