# Was "other" flag renamed to "in need of moderator intervention"?

Tags: support, flags

I just noticed that in place of the prior ["Other" flag option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALa0y.png) (that was right there yesterday), there is a new text:

> **in need of moderator intervention**
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. *Be specific and detailed!*

Is this a recent change? Why it was introduced and where can I find more about it?

Comment: ...I've seen this new text at SO, MSO, MSE, Programmers, Workplace - change looks network-wide

Comment: Maybe it was changed with [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290915/426671)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was introduced this morning.

The intent is the same as "other", with wording that *hopefully* makes it a bit more clear what flagging should be used for. The nature of the flag and how it is handled are unchanged.

### Background

We repeatedly get complaints (on meta and via email) about problems that should be reported to moderators. Simultaneously, moderators (particularly on SO) are frequently frustrated by "other" flags that have more specific flag types (spam, close) or aren't problems moderators can handle in the first place ("i need an answer urgently!").

The hope here is that this change (along with other wording changes made to that dialog) encourages folks to use the proper flag type for problems that have one, and avoid it for problems that don't require moderation at all.

Of course, we'll be monitoring folks' actual behavior to see if this works.

Comment: You planning on changing the "other" for comment flags?

Comment: @Roombatron5000 That's a [whole another kettle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252844/make-comment-flags-less-stupid).