# Do we need comments saying what comments are for?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I am seeing a more frequent use of comments on a question that are posted right after the question is stating what the purpose of comments are.

The question and comment get posted within seconds of each other by the same person.

Do we need these comments or should they be treated like others that common and not needed?

> Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted.

This is a comment that I am seeing more often across multiple sites and I think that it isn't a comment that is needed on a question especially if it is posted right after the question is asked.

Should comments like this get added to the list of ones that get auto deleted with a single flag?

If we really need these types of comments to help remind users what comments are for shouldn't it be something system generated that is a part of every post on the site? This way it would be something that would help all users instead of just the users that know to add it or have some sort of script that auto adds it.

Comment: Unless this is a systemic problem where *many* users are posting such comments on multiple sites, then, generally, no, such shouldn't be added to the auto-single-flag deletion. It would be reasonable for you to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag *on a post* on the site(s) where you're seeing some of these and inform moderators that you're seeing a bunch of them, with links to the posts where you've seen them and/or users you've seen post them. Moderators can then clean them up in bulk and/or message the user(s) posting the comments (or handle it however they see as appropriate).

Comment: Note: I specifically said raise the flag *on a post*, because flags on comments aren't guaranteed to be seen by a moderator, as they are marked helpful and removed from the mod flag dashboard when the comment is deleted.

Comment: @Makyen I have been flagging them as not needed anymore and not sure how much moderator time should be spent on these types of comments.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested the above course of action, as it should minimize the overall person-time to handle the situation. From the contents and peremptory nature of the comments, it's likely these are being posted by a relatively small number of users. Moderators can search through a user's comments and delete matching ones in bulk. Moderators can also message the user(s) and, hopefully, get the user(s) to stop posting such peremptory comments (assuming the comments are peremptory and not in response to other comments that have already been deleted, and the mods feel it's a problem).

Comment: I think we can all appreciate the irony of that comment not being what that comment says comments are for.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That is the purpose of the question, if something like that is really needed it should be a system generated message to alert users and not something that users need to do.

Comment: @Makyen Wouldn't it be much faster to just allow a single flag to delete it? I can't imagine that updating that logic would take much work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comment deletion events in the revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306297/comment-deletion-events-in-the-revisions-list)

Comment: @Joachim No, I am not asking about keeping a history of what was deleted.

Comment: @JoeW I get that, but the answer by Catija there explains thoroughly why comments get deleted, and why it is necessary to point out what they are for (nevertheless, answers shouldn't be used to close questions as duplicates, so I'll retract my vote).

Comment: @Joachim My question is asking if a type of comment should be added to the rules that auto delete it for a single flag. If we really need something to indicate what comments are for shouldn't it be part of every post?

Answer (score 4):

> The question and comment get posted within seconds of each other by the same person

That makes a big difference. Presumably they are trying to stave off criticisms.

Otherwise: SO Inc onboarding/education is atrocious so it is left to users to educate each other.

Whether asker-posted premptively or otherwise, it seems pretty rare (i.e. not preceded by problematic comments) to be writing special code for. And in the former case it's bad behaviour meriting a flag for a moderator to address.

Cases in the Google cache are from very poor posts. Some have the same rudeness & "this will be deleted fast". Some posts & users are deleted. It doesn't seem like such cases attempting to preempt other comments are worth bothering about by new means. Some are clearly the same person, maybe all of them. Such bad behaviour should be addressed specifically. I flagged for a moderator asking this to be looked at cross-account cross-site.

Comment: If that is truly the case this is something that should be systematically generated on every post that is made and not depend on user knowledge (or script) to post.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's useful sometimes.

Sometimes I see people using the canned comments from review queues telling people who posted a non-answer to post it as a comment instead, when what the answer body was would be inappropriate for a comment as well. In that case, I comment to educate both the person who posted the canned comment, and the person who received it. And it's not like the comment I add is going to clutter anything of importance up. The non-answer's going down anyway.

And... y'know- the fact that sometimes mods leave such comments telling people to not have noisy, or irrelevant, or extended discussions in comments after cleaning those comments up / sending them to chat.

There are probably more scenarios where this is useful, but I'm too lazy to think of them right now.

Comment: If that is truly the case this is something that should be systematically generated on every post that is made and not depend on user knowledge (or script) to post.