# Lost 'comment' button on interpersonal.stackexchange (even though I have 101 rep)

Tags: support, comments

I seem to have lost all 'comment' buttons on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ . My reputation is sufficient and I did comment in the past.

What could be the reason?

Comment: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839

Comment: You're now supposed to **only** *suggest improvements*

Comment: @animuson That would be an answer, and I would accept it. :-)

Comment: Voting to reopen, this feature started on Area 51, and it might well be applied on more sites. (/cc @Sonic.)

Comment: On closing, if off-topic, what would have been the right site to ask? It's not an IPS question.

Comment: @Jeffrey The question has already been asked and answered on IPS meta. https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2878/why-cant-i-add-comments It's possible that you're not aware, but each site has its own meta, where it is appropriate to ask questions about that site. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, this specific site is running an experiment (for a month) where they renamed the button to "[suggest improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299195/fixing-comments-in-5-minutes-intrigued-lets-discuss)" so they have:

- Fewer comments.
- Fewer comment flags.
- Lower ratio of deleted comments.
- More upvotes per comment.
- More edits following comments.

Comment: And it was supposed to be a secret so as to not influence the statistics too much! :P

Comment: And this question proves it's working since whatever the OP wanted to comment, it apparently did not qualify as "suggest improvement"

Comment: @KateGregory nope, sorry. Not only did it delay my "comment" by an hour, it turned out to be something that would improve the answer: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/how-to-ask-why-i-was-not-included-without-causing-a-scene/14059#comment57308_14059