Community Asks Sprint Announcement and Results - September 2024
Update - October 9, 2024
We were able to work on quite a few issues during this sprint, some we previously told you about in the original post below, and others that were left over from the first Community Asks Sprint or completely new ones.
Although this was only the second ever Community Asks Sprint, we are seeing the benefits of successive sprint planning that build off one another from quarter to quarter. They allow for dedicated discovery or design effort that needs more refinement to get them ready for completion in the next sprint.
For example, some additional discovery and design work was completed on an item from the last sprint, Tell users when their edits are rejected; additional updates were made this sprint to the notice banners for suggested edits. The changes should help with banner blindness when appropriate and align better with Stack's Notice component usage guidelines. There are now five versions of this notice, depending on the user’s scenario with regard to suggested edits.
Here are some highlights of issues we were able to resolve as a part of this sprint:

Can the new duplicate comment make “edit” a magic link
Remove the suggestion to post a new question from the closed questions post notices
Indicator on Meta next to the display name of former Staff and/or Mod users for actions performed with that status
Usernames that consist solely of Zalgo text can't be clicked when associated with a post
Gold tag badges don't apply to synonymized tags
Half of the New Privilege message is in a language i don't speak
Hiding downvoted questions silences important discussions on Meta
Delete vote retraction logic is confusing
It's not possible to unfollow a deleted discussion
How to find a question by its old tag when that tag is synonymized with another

One issue we’d also like to call attention to is the Are there plans to switch to the current version of MathJax? in which @KyleMit spent the sprint investigating how we might go about upgrading our MathJax version from 2.x to 3.x+, as had been requested in several places explained in this post.
Although we couldn’t get to everything, we appreciate you taking the time to submit requests on this post. Moderators, thanks for tagging relevant posts as status-review and users, keep voting! We will continue to take all of these into consideration in prioritizing the backlog requests that get worked on next.
We’re excited to continue refining this into a repeatable, efficient process for subsequent quarterly sprints. Please let us know what you think of the second Community Asks Sprint and any feedback you may have. Hopefully this will continue to be a way for us to address inconveniences, bugs, and requests around the network. We’re looking forward to future iterations, and hope you are too!

Update - September 30, 2024
Last week, we completed our Community Asks Sprint! Well, mostly. There are still a few lingering items that need to be addressed to wrap it up. To that end, we won't be sharing our post-community asks sprint summary until next week, which will list everything we were able to address this time around.

Update – September 10, 2024: Thank you everyone for submitting your issues and requests; we appreciate you taking the time to raise them. Keep them coming. We will take these into consideration alongside our existing process for reviewing and prioritizing the requests that get worked on during these sprints. Expect another update a week or two after the sprint finishes; we’ll let the community know how it went and share the highlights of issues we were able to tackle.

My name is Caroline, but some of my friends call me Carot. I’m a staff member on our Product Marketing team and I work closely with the Community team here at Stack Overflow. I’m also a first time Meta poster, it’s great to connect with you all. Let’s dive in.
In June, we spent a sprint addressing your requests and introduced the “Community Asks Sprint”. The Community Asks Sprint is dedicated time, across all our public-facing developer teams, to work exclusively on requests that have come in from the community. This quarterly sprint allows us to prioritize work on requests and reports that could otherwise remain backlogged for long periods of time because they may be outside the scope of roadmap priorities.
The first sprint was well received, but we heard you in wanting a heads-up before work began for the next one, which is the purpose of this post. As this was a new initiative for our company, across many different departments, and the core team was tasked to plan and establish a process for longevity, we wanted to surprise and delight, not knowing how much we would be able to accomplish in a short period of time. However, now that we have a solid foundation in place, we are happy to announce our next Community Asks Sprint will be September 23rd - September 27th, 2024.
Here are some highlights we are hoping to work on in the upcoming sprint (note that we may or may not get to all of these, we may get to more, or we may decide to triage different issues):

Improve onboarding guidance for new reviewers in review queues
Hiding downvoted questions silences important discussions on Meta
Empty content field creation bug
Comment rate limits are not enforced

As stated in the previous announcement post - moderators, thanks for tagging relevant posts as status-review so keep it up, we’ll review those items that end up on our board. The intention is to balance age and score, so that we can ensure we are looking at issues that you still care about, now. And users, don’t forget to vote! While we won’t ever rely solely on voting to determine our priorities, votes are a critical signal that lets us evaluate how much you want us to implement a feature on the network.
Are there any issues that you’d like to see us explore either in this Community Asks Sprint or a future one? We will take these into consideration alongside our existing process for reviewing and prioritizing the requests that get worked on during these sprints.
We will provide an update to this post a week or two after the sprint finishes and let the community know how it went and the highlights of issues we were able to tackle.

Welcome to Meta, Carot! Thank you, sincerely, for the heads-up this time around, and giving us the opportunity to point out a few things we'd like to see some engineering time on.

I assume this is just about development related request / issues, right?

Is it pronounced like "Carrot" or "Tarot"? :)

would it be possible / a good idea to feature these sprint announcement posts?

@Spevacus I agree with starball. Why isn't this being featured? (/cc Carot)

@ShadowWizard From my understanding the community team typically handles the featuring since it's network-wide. I'll poke a CM and see if they're game for featuring it. I'm a little late to the game but I'll see what I can do.

@Spevacus shouldn't this get [tag:featured]? p.s. I only became aware of this since someone shared a link in SOCVR.

@M-- I pinged a CM but didn't hear back. It's a bit late now to feature it (the sprint begins on the 23rd) but I'll be more annoying next time.

@ShadowWizard There's limited space for featured posts (or more accurately, CMs around the world learned long ago that the more you pin/feature, the less that gets read, haha). At the time of this posting, there was a lot going on, so we made the call not to feature. That said, we will feature the post when we update it after the sprint (and I'll make a note in our retro for the next one to try and schedule the upcoming announcement for the next one at a time when it can be featured. Thanks for the ping and hope it helps in the future.

@Dalmarus that makes sense. (but it would have been nice to hear this logic closer to when shadow and I first asked about it).

@starball You're not wrong. Been a busy month and I missed it. Only noticed today because someone pinged me personally. My apologies, especially since I'm one of the people that should have been paying closer attention to the comments on here.

Thanks for the update and all the work you've done! I look forward to the next one. For the next sprint post, @Carot, can you please consider including a list of requests from this sprint that didn't quite make it (for example, the top-requested feature here was one I posted (albeit late), and it did not get implemented this go-round... hopefully that means it jumps to (near) the top of the queue for the next sprint) that you plan to work on in that next sprint? Otherwise we may see users post repeat answers requesting the same things that were requested this time.

@TylerH The planning process is started before the actual sprint to sort requests, determine what aspects need UI/Design/etc work before they can go to a developer, etc. Requests that come in during the actual week of the sprint (September 23rd - September 27th) would be too late to be implemented.
It's definitely getting upvotes though, so If it's not already, would you make it a standalone Meta post and ping me when it's up? I'll mark it as Status-Review.

@Dalmarus Sure, that makes sense. My question is whether items that came in too late for this sprint, but are highly upvoted, will automatically be added (or at least considered) to the schedule during the next sprint. I can make a Meta post if I need to, but since it's already here, if it's already going to be considered, a separate post would just be duplicating content.

@TylerH They should be added to the review list (there are 100+ each time we run that query), but that requires someone to manually come back to this post and add them (which again, should be done, but we're all human so mistakes can happen) - it'll also be a different set of people doing the preparation part for the next sprint, since that duty rotates). That's a long way of saying, yep, it should be, but by creating a post that we then tag with status-review, it's guaranteed to get on the review list automatically. ;)

@Dalmarus Per your request, posted here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403657/allow-moderators-to-change-the-outcome-of-a-handled-flag :-)

@TylerH Awesome. Status-review tag added. Thanks!

Please allow moderators to change the outcome of a handled flag, such as when they accidentally/prematurely decline a flag they ultimately want to mark as helpful, instead.
This is a minor issue but is one that continues to crop up on a regular basis. As I'm not a moderator anywhere, I can't provide any kind of stats on this, but it's something that moderators ought to be able to do, especially given they are supposed to be "exception handlers".

Per staff request, I posted this as a standalone feature request: Allow moderators to change the outcome of a handled flag

This should also allow changing in the opposite direction: when flag that should have been declined was marked helpful. Some helpful flags turn the post into audits and removing bad audits can be cumbersome at times. Ability to change the flag outcome would help solving such cases more easily.

Bringing Meta and Chat to the sidebar
 copied nearly in its entirety from here - much like Bernie Sanders, I am once again asking :D 
In the old days, the links to meta and chat were front and center in the top bar. They're hidden under the SE/hamburger menu and its hugely unintuitive. This practically results in underutilisation of tools helpful for a healthy community - our second space (meta) and third space (chat) could use more love.
It also means it's a lot clearer to users how to find the per site meta or main chatroom for the site
Especially considering the whole intent of the sidebar initially was to inline teams into regular sites, and teams essentially is its own thing now, it seems a better use of that space

100%. I'd love to hear what the UX team thought from the last time this was brought up too

Please fix the fix you had for Inbox notifications not consistently marked as read after clicking title I'm clicking the same message multiple times to get it to clear, is it broken, or is something else happening? from the last Community Asks sprint. So that we could once again open things in tabs. The only sane way I can manage my inbox is:

Open one tab.
Open the notification bar.
Open one notification in the same tab.
Repeat 2-3 until no unread notifications are left.

It gets annoying if you have to deal with 10+ notifications. Which I often have to more than once a day.

It's already tagged with status-review, but I have to point a big sign at Flag window redux: proposed syntax. This is a mini-overhaul on the wording used in the flagging dialog box.
The language improvements here are fantastic, because a bunch of ambiguity is removed in several places. Some highlights:

Each flag describes what the flagger wants to have happen. E.g. "I think this post should be... Deleted as spam". When first getting involved with SE, users don't really know that red flags are basically votes to delete. Further, the descriptions are more encompassing of the kinds of things that red flags are meant for.
The removal of "needs improvement" is something we've wanted for a long time, even though folks have been far less vocal about it lately. Like Machavity says: The post notice says "closed", the privilege used to close stuff is called "close votes"... Why do we hide this behind "Needs improvement" still? You've made several changes to post notices, featuring guidance depending upon who looks at them (i.e. post authors get special guidance that's tailored to them). We don't need the ambiguity of "needs improvement" anymore. Closure isn't a death sentence for a question, and that's always prominently displayed to the question asker.
The mod intervention flag description got some expansion that loosely adds "If there's something you want to add extra context for, use this!" which is really important for mods to understand where a flagger is coming from.

I could go on all day about how great the changes are, but I'll get off my soap box now.

Please fix this bug preventing us from submitting edits that contain an image. This has been reported on Meta Stack Overflow here: False-positive "Your post is mostly images."

Another inbox-related request, but it'd be great if filtering unread inbox notifications actually showed my unread notifications.
I still have two unread messages and gosh do I wish I knew what they were.

As a recap, selecting "unread" applies a local filter on the inbox items and does not go out to find unread items in the full inbox. The link to the full inbox is unhelpful because there aren't any filters there to find unread items so my only option would be to look through literally hundreds of pages of notifications to find the two which are unread.

Additionally being able to search or filter on the full inbox page would be, y'know, great. As well as changing the number of entries shown per page.

I have several hundred unread inbox notifications that I can't practically access.  Certainly including some mod messages that should have gotten replies.

Can we finally get the badges for finding duplicates? See It's time to reward the duplicate finders;
That is the most upvoted question with status-review on Meta Stack Overflow, and I think other communities would also appreciate this. I could try and make the case for it here, but I think the linked question already does a great job. If you are not planning to implement this, at least give us an update after 4+ years.

The flag/close dialog has several serious issues. The easiest way to see these is to review the responses to Question Close Updates, most of which have been unacknowledged (publicly) by staff.
Issues include:

The flagging dialog should not put all the custom close reasons under the heading of "needs improvement"
The "needs more focus" reason is not only about posts that ask multiple questions. It is also about questions that are too broad and which it is unreasonable to expect to be answered in the SE Q&A format.
When you've voted to close with a site-specific close reason, you can't see which one you chose at a later time

Please consider implementing Machavity's very clear proposal.

Eh, forgot about it, and reported a bug there as well. Well to be honest it's not on top of my bugs list, bug meh... whatever they do will be better than what we have now. :) (was going to edit the typo but then decided it's too funny, so leaving it)

Another text-based change would be finishing the work I'd started here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388030/improving-the-copy-in-the-close-modal-and-post-notices-2023-edition  That said, I don't personally like the "make red flags have red text" element of Machavity's post.

Since you're already looking at closing/reviewing, might I recommend y'all wrap up this project I'd started last year?
Improving the copy in the close modal and post notices – 2023 edition
While there's still some slight adjustments that could be done, even as proposed, the new text will be miles better than the existing text. If I get some time, I may try to post a new answer with an updated version of the text based on feedback. The subjective question close reason is still the most finicky.

Can I request rethinking how associated with  (Twitter) we want to be?
In particular: Is it time to reconsider Social Media links in "Share" and User Profiles, etc?

I don't think this will happen, there are too many gains to having social media links. As long as relevant actors have an account everyone else will also think twitter is relevant.

At the very least they should update the name and icon everywhere to reflect that it's going to a site called X, not a site called Twitter. But yes it would be preferable if they replaced it with a generic "Social Media" field.

I'm not sure if this is the place to ask this, but it seems like you're asking for suggestions on things to look at so I'll bring this up here. Over a decade ago 15 years ago, this request was status-declined: Please add the ability to fold blocks of code in questions and answers However, as you can see, it is pretty well received. And as this answer notes, there is standard HTML which does pretty much exactly what is asked for. It would be nice if you could look into adding the <details>/<summary> tags to your list of allowed tags.
A couple of years ago (back when that was the process), I had tried to flag it so that a mod could tag it for review, but that flag was sadly declined with a stock reason.

You should probably open another question for new HTML elements. (Actually, I might, if you don't… I have a list, you see.)

High chance it will just get closed as a duplicate -_-'

I'll take that bet.

@wizzwizz4 how do you want to go about it? A question per tag/family of tags, or a single overarching question with individual answers for tags?

I was going to just list all the useful HTML elements in a question, perhaps with motivation.

That could work, but the worry I have is that people opposed to some subset of requested tags will oppose the whole request - and I have seen that happen when a single request asks for multiple things. It really makes it hard to garner support.

I suppose I'll procrastinate less on posting it if I can do it piecemeal, too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Yeah, Jeff gut-reaction declined that request because he has a weird personal vendetta against the concept of code folding. It should never have been declined out of hand like that, but it certainly should have had its status-declined tag simply removed as soon as he left the company.Adding support for details/summary formatting within posts would be a huge modernization boon for exceedingly little effort by comparison, so you get my +1.

@muru Posted a separate question.

Wow, the Jon Skeet answered the question, and Jeff Atwood was the one who marked it as declined. That really dates this.

My two cents bugs that I'd like to see fixed:

Follow popup won't clear (without refresh)
Can't delete the filter called My Filter

Both are old time bugs, and likely easy (?) to fix.
Thanks!

P.S.
In case it's done, I hereby promise 1k points for each in bounties. :) (And no, it's not a bribe. ;))

It is sooooba bribe

Another moderator tool change that I'd love to see finally addressed is refreshing network profiles. Currently, any time the network profile needs to be touched, staff needs to be involved. Allowing mods to handle this would mean things are handled faster and don't take up limited CM team time.


Are there any issues that you’d like to see us explore either in this Community Asks Sprint or a future one?

Since you asked, here's a subset of my personal wishlist (I didn't include some stuff that I consider lower value, or some stuff that I imagine to be harder or more controversial to implement. For the record, yes, I have the self-awareness to feel awkward about the fact that I've listed much more here than everyone else. Also, just for context to the reader, I'm more on the power user end of the spectrum, so many of these requests are pretty high-value for me, but not to the average user):

Add an option to sort answers by the viewer's previously cast votes 
Inbox is no longer immediately marking item as read when middle-clicking to open in new tab 
Autofocus body input field when opening inline editor for answer posts 
Disable annoying autofocus when clicking preview 
Notification when a trivial edit is made on my post 
When in a specific SE site, could there be an easy way to see that site's manifesto? 
Enable autoselect for post owner / post revisions keyboard shortcut 
Add a keyboard shortcut for adding a post to saves 
There should be some way to check which list a saved post is in, and what private notes you have given it — from the post's page. 
Make saves listing visually indicate deleted answers 
Help new users by making tagging smarter 

Moderation stuff:

Option to delete an answer only visible after a reload 
Code blocks wrap on new-answers-old-questions

Long lines in blockquote breaks layout in 10k mod tools


Allow another close vote after retraction 
status-completed (?) Make the "delete" button different when you already voted to delete 
Don't show the contents of a post that was deleted as "rude/abusive" in New Answers to Old Questions 


Make comment flagging work more like chat flagging, available to users with 10k reputation

Make community comment moderation a more public process


How to search my flag history by specific keywords? 
Send custom flag responses to messages inbox 
Allow sorting flags by handling time instead of flagging time on the flag history/summary page 

Review queues:

Bring a "human factor" into review audit composition/selection 
Practice queues for review training

Give new edit reviewers some audits to begin with


Allow us to additionally filter off-topic close reasons in the Close Vote Review Queue 


Note that one of your planned changes may(?) also address Show MSE posts authored by staff members on the homepage regardless of the vote count

Improve suggest edits

The implementation of the request Tell users when edits have been rejected simply does not work.
Please just add a regular notification, as you already do with approved edits!  As to why it does not work, I have pointed that out in the comments to the official answer and here. I aleady made a feature request in MSO.

There are tons of ideas floating around to free up the suggest-edit queue. Please just implement any of them like For edit-suggestors with a streak of N approvals, only require one approval for their next suggested edit, Opining a successful-edit-count-based two tier suggested edit system



My preferred suggested edits fix is to stop having edit privileges be rep based and, instead, base it on suggested edit success rates - many users are great at editing without ever managing to earn >2k rep - so you get more reviewers and have fewer people suggesting edits in the first place because they've (hopefully) earned the ability to edit freely.

None of those would work because there aren't any official SE editing guidelines, so a minimum quorum of 2 reviewers is necessary. Besides, I had 500 approved suggested edits when I started to understand all the criteria put together, and I still see plenty of high rep users rejecting valid edits based on some decade old post that just happened to be upvoted. There won't be any magic solution without an official set of editing guidelines.

@bad_coder any suggestion is better than the current state. I'd say I am an ok editor, but i only occasionally edits posts (and thus only slowly get better at it) as I have to judge whether it is worth one of my five (or less) available edit slots and if the queue is not full again. Same reason I also stopped (or never really started) doing any reviews, from the comments of past (and oftentimes rejected) proposals I know that this happens quite a bit.

In the previous community ask sprint, we have introduced the suggested edits canceled and Tell users when their edits are rejected features in  Meta Stack Overflow.
But I find a bug that related to the suggested edits canceled, the question has no “status” tag recently, I’m not sure will it be fixed on upcoming community asks sprint notice, but I hope it will be fixed. The question is:

If my suggested edit is canceled, there should not be a notice saying my edit is rejected

Also, I hope this two years old issue fixed, the question has a status-review tag:

The site icons in all the dropdowns in the top bar on the chat page seem to have... disappeared??


In the future, feel free to flag your question for status-review. I'll leave it be for now given that you've mentioned it here, but it has plenty of votes (indicating community recognition of a problem) and seems perfectly reasonable. In other words: Your question would've gotten the status tag had it been brought to our attention.

There's a discrepancy in how URL links are validated on posts, that cropped up around the time of the Imgur migration earlier this year.
The post validation no longer allows protocol-relative links only for images (despite allowing them in the past). For non-image URLs, protocol relative links are still supported:
Url protocol should not be required for image links
I raise it here because it's probably a minor fix and something that could fit within a sprint.

As for how to solve it: I'd prefer protocol-relative be allowed again for images, but ultimately it's the discrepancy that needs to be resolved - either we support it or we don't.

Please add the list of recent flags to /admin on chat. As far as I understand, it's a five-minute change that'll help make people aware of a useful tool that you currently need to already know about to access. I've poked... multiple people across the past few years about this but it's never actually been addressed.

I believe this could be a quick fix/addition, that would really improve the editing flow at times:
Add an option to leave a "This is a duplicate answer" comment when voting to delete an answer from review
This, and/or adding an option for a "duplicate answer" flag, as mentioned in an answer to that request.
This might not be a priority for some sites in the network that have less factual or binary answers/solutions, but for many (among which SO), it would be a great aid.

You asked what we'd like to see you work on.  I think it would be great to implement the change proposed by Shog9 and Robert Cartaino:

Under each question, rename "Add a comment" to "Ask for clarification"
Under each answer, rename "Add a comment" to "Suggest improvements"

See https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2839/1710, Experiment concluded: a comment by any other name, and Fixing comments in 5 minutes. Intrigued? Let's discuss.

That's not all comments are useful for, so this would be a problematic change.

I can understand that view, though I don't agree.  You can find that criticism leveled and considered in the links that I link to.  Every change has positives and negatives, and I think the links I provided offer evidence that the positives outweigh the negatives.

How come there is nothing here on MSE? If there is, please link to it instead, easier to handle than digging through several different places.

@ShadowWizard that last link is to MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299195/160917

@D.W. If we make this suggestion, we severely limit the utility of comments. No more useful relevant asides, no more replies from authors that aren't directly part of the answer, no more auto-comments that aren't requests for clarification on Qs or improvement suggestions on As, etc. Given that there isn't actually an issue with how the comment phrasing is worded today, I don't see that there are any benefits to such a change; users can still click "Suggest improvements" and write "+1 thanks for this".

Instead, a regex (yes, haha, preemptive "regex are bad" remark) would probably be better to detect problematic content in comments and warn/block users at the time of posting.

Now, if you want to fundamentally change what action someone can take when they click these links, then that's another story. If a list of prescribed questions popped up, along with a "custom request for clarification" option for free text, and likewise for answers, I don't think I'd be opposed to this. But that would be altogether separate from the comment function, and presumably wouldn't be couched behind a 50 rep requirement.


some of my friends call me Carot. (...) I’m also a first time Meta poster

Hi Carot



Sprint is dedicated time

and Usain Bolt is the GOAT


Can you fix New activity indicator (bullet/dot) in Custom Filters no longer displaying ?
