# Show Deleted Comment in Expanded Question View in Flag Queue

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, comment-flags

When handling flags (and especially comment flags), it would be beneficial to be able to see the deleted comments on a post.

For example, user A makes a comment, user B replies, user A deletes their comment and flags user B's for being obsolete.

Currently, in order to see it properly, I need to open the post in a new tab, view the deleted comments from there, then handle the flag(s).

It would be awesome to have the "view deleted comments" action in the flag queue as well.

Comment: While I agree that this would improve things, I think the resources for implementing this are better spent on [not having moderators deal with obsolete flags in the first place (at least most of the time)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252883/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I tend to agree. But smaller changes are more likely to be implemented in the short term.

Comment: I am no expert, but both seem equally difficult to implement to me.